# Terraform provisioner is not working - Permission denied

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I am running below provisioner part in terraform while creating instance. But its not working, showing permission denied error.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | sed -e 's/#MaxStartups 10:30:60/MaxStartups 10:30:60/' >/etc/ssh/sshd_config1",
      "sudo mv -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config1 /etc/ssh/sshd_config"
    ]
  }
```

or

```
provisioner "file" {
    source      = "script.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/script.sh"
  }
```

I am getting below error:

> Error :cannot create /etc/ssh/sshd_config: Permission denied
>   or Permission denied

Comment: the error clearly says you dont have permissions to edit `sshd_config` file on your local box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with terraform you could run the remote-exec as root user if root login is allowed until this step - then using sudo would be obsolete.

Another approach could be using the sudo NOPASSWD option ([read more](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334318/sudoers-file-enable-nopasswd-for-user-all-commands)).

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Terraform provisioner `remote-exec` to change something in the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` which needs the root permission, the command `sudo` is interactive that you need to input the password to get the root permission, but the provisioner is not. So you cannot input the password in the provisioner so that it shows you do not have the permission.

The Terraform provisioner just likes running a script inside the VM and it does not support the interactive actions as I know. If you want to do the interactive activities with the 
VM, just use the SSH connection without Terraform.

**Update**

Use SSH command to connect into the VM:

```
ssh user@vm_ip
```

Then inside the VM you can execute the command as you want.

Comment: Can you please suggest how it can be done through SSH?

Comment: @Guru Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Guru I didn't see any more updates. What is the situation now?

Comment: Looks like its working with remote-exec and I could able to modify.